# How to do canvas operations with Complex numbers

Tags: android, fft, complex-numbers

I want to use [FastFourierTransformer](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6.1/org/apache/commons/math3/transform/FastFourierTransformer.html) to convert [AudioRecord](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord) ByteArray from time domain to frequency domain. Ultimately, I want to use the frequencies to draw on the Canvas. However, FastFourierTransformer returns complex numbers, is there a way I can use these complex numbers to draw on the Canvas?

Comment: Two suggestions. Read: [Why does FFT produce complex numbers instead of real numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10304532/295004), and have you seen: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer

Comment: @MorrisonChang Thanks for the links. I now understand I only need the magnitudes, which are the amplitudes. I calculated it by:

 `val doubles = byteArray.map { it.toDouble() }.toDoubleArray()
 val amplitudes = FastFourierTransformer(DftNormalization.STANDARD).transform(doubles, TransformType.FORWARD).map { (it).multiply(it.conjugate()).sqrt().real  }.joinToString()}`


`byteArray` is the result of polling `AudioRecord`. I tried using the Visualizer class earlier it doesn't work for `AudioRecord. Setting the Aaudio session to `0` doesn't work either.

Comment: To get the magnitude of each complext number,  I multiplied it with its conjugate and got the square root of the multiplication.

Comment: The magnitudes I am getting are pretty large, though, even when the recording should be silent or nearly silent.